# Why the devDependencies for TailwindCSS not working?

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, tailwind-css, package.json

I noticed when installing Tailwind with `-D` `(devDependencies)` based on their documentation, my Tailwind did not work on my projects (React,NextJs). Later I need to uninstall and reinstall w/o `-D` just so the package will be in the `dependencies` part of `pacakage.json`.

I just want to know the reason behind it, because other tutorials they will use the `-D` and it works.

Comment: have you tried   `npx tailwindcss init` ?

Comment: Yes, of course. 

what i notice if th `tailwindcss` in `devDependencies` it wont work unless in `deependencies`.